# I know svn & git. How to grok Perforce?

Tags: svn, git, perforce

I have lots of experience with svn, some with git. What a good tl;dr for Perforce, to help me grok it?

Answer (score 2):

They have video tutorials [here](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/media_library/tutorials.html). When I used it a few years back it was very intuitive. If you are familiar with SVN and git you shouldn't have any problems.

Hm, sorry, this may be too time consuming an answer. I am sure others more familiar with this can provide a better answer.

Answer (score 2):

The link posted by omerhuhammed is good - my only problem is that they are not listed in a good order if you are looking to get started.  I would probably look at the following:

- Basic SCM Operations in Perforce
- Workspace Concepts and Setup in P4V

As the two basic starter videos.  Additionally, they have a small getting started manual [here](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/r10.2/manuals/intro/index.html), which describes the basics of client workspaces, syncing, and editing files.  There is getting started manual for P4V (their GUI front end) [here](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/r10.2/manuals/p4v-gs/index.html) if you would rather use the GUI.

I don't know what your threshold is for tl;dr, but the above should cover the basics of what you need to know.